# Determine how diagonal 2D Vector is

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate the amount (defined as a value $0.0 \rightarrow 1.0$) that a 2D Vector is diagonal.
for example

- A vector of $(1,1)$ is perfectly diagonal so would have a diagonal
  value of $1.0$
- A vector of $(1,0)$ is perfectly NOT diagonal so would have
  a diagonal value of$ 0.0$

I also need to account for all $4$ directions, so
$(-1,1)$ is also perfectly diagonal as well as $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,-1).$

The solution I am looking for is for a piece of software so ideally would be efficent in terms of processing (no sqrts etc).

I have tried a few things (like using the DOT product against a fixed vector $(1,1),$ and getting the value of the DOT product - as a DoT product of $2$ parallel Vectors is $1$)

Comment: Dot product is great, just make sure the vector is normalized.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your easiest method is, for a vector $(x,y)$
$$\dfrac{\min\{|x|,|y|\}}{\max\{|x|,|y|\}}$$

Or algorithmically,

```
Diag(x, y)
    a = abs(x)
    b = abs(y)
    if (a > b) then exchange a, b
    if (b == 0) then return 1
    return a / b
```

where I'm considering $(0,0)$ to be "perfectly diagonal", but you can make your own call on that.